# for OpenGL, is client API version number the OpenGL version number?

Tags: opengl, glfw

[In the link here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#GLFW_STEREO) It says that:

> GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR and GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR specify the
> client API version that the created context must be compatible with.
> The exact behavior of these hints depends on the requested client API.
> I am also following this [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window)

Is it true that for the functions:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

the numbers I put inside the functions will be the version number of my OpenGL?
so for example if I have OpenGL version 4.6, I would put:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

The client API that you are using would be OpenGL, and those window hints are for when you create OpenGL context. When using glfwWindowHint() for GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR/MINOR, you are requesting that version of OpenGL. Depending on what your GPU supports, you may get that, or you may get an earlier version.

Side note - You cannot get the latest version your GPU supports at runtime, but you can get the version of the created context with glGetString(GL_VERSION).

Comment: "Depending on what your GPU supports, you may get that, or you may get an earlier version." No, that's not what happens. YOu mag get what you asked for directly, or any compatible version (which means any _higher_ version which has not removed any old features still present in the version you requested). YOu will never get a lower version than requested, the GL context creation (and with GLFW, the whole window creation) will  just fail.